# Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-server-side

I am getting following exception when calling an Asp.NET Core 3.1 web api from a Blazor app.
But same code works great from visual studio debugging

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HttpClientJsonExtensions.SendJsonAsync[T](HttpClient httpClient, HttpMethod method, String requestUri, Object content)*
```

UI Code:

```cs
public async Task<bool> UpdateCOAValue(COALookUps dataItem)
{
    bool result = false;
    
    try
    {
        bool response = await _httpClient.SendJsonAsync<bool>(HttpMethod.Put, string.Format(@_webApi.WebAPIUrl, "update"), dataItem);
        result = await Task.FromResult(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Error: {0}", ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Web API Controller Method:

```cs
[HttpPut("update")]
public bool UpdateCOAEntry([FromBody]COALookups value)
{
    try
    {
        List<SqlParameter> lstSQLParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
        SqlParameter paramCOALookUpID = new SqlParameter();
        //other code
        dbManager.Update("UpdateCOALookUp", CommandType.StoredProcedure, lstSQLParams.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Error: {0}", ex);
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Web API Controllers syntax:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class COAController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Comment: What's the value assigned to `@_webApi.WebAPIUrl`?

Comment: Also -- and I don't think this has to do with your problem -- what's the purpose of wrapping `response` in a `Task` to assign it to `result`?

Comment: I have made its async to make GUI responsive , it works great in visual studio end to end debugging ( GUI to Web API) only deployment server (IIS) server it fails

Comment: It would be "just as async" if you omitted that line and wrote `result = await _httpClient.SendJsonAsync...` on the line above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. (this is a workaround), will have to redo this after each release. Please post if anyone has a better solution.

1. Open WebDav Authoring Rules and then select Disable WebDAV option
   present on the right bar.
2. Select Modules, find the WebDAV Module and remove it.
3. Select HandlerMapping, find the WebDAVHandler and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution working than changing any settings in IIS
In ConfigureServices method add following

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
    AllowAutoRedirect = true
};
    
services.AddSingleton(sp =>
    new HttpClient(handler)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["WebAPI:BaseUrl"])
    });
```